# ReactJs: Unexpected token Error

Tags: reactjs

I am running this tests using Mocha with following configuration in my npm package.json

```
 "scripts": {"test": "mocha './app/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register"}
```

and this results in the following error

> employeeGrid.row.spec.jsx: Unexpected token (8:12)

Notice that line 8:12 is the following: `return (<tr>`

```
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import expect from 'expect-jsx';
//import GridRow from './employeeGrid.row.jsx'

class GridRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<tr>
      <td>{this.props.employee.name}</td>
      <td>{this.props.employee.position}</td>
      <td>{this.props.employee.yearStarted}</td>
    </tr>)
  }
}
describe('Grid Row', () => {
  it('Row Actions Test', ()=> {
    let employee = {
      "name": "Person",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "yearStarted": 2010
    };

    // shallow render
    // renders only one level deep
    const renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    renderer.render(<GridRow employee={employee}/>);
    const output = renderer.getRenderOutput();
    console.log(output);
  });
});
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you're using babel? what does your `.babelrc` file look like?

Comment: https://github.com/eugenekgn/reactjs-tests/blob/master/.babelrc it's right here, but all the other es6(2015) work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With babel 6.0, JSX is no longer processed by default, nor is it processed with the `es2015` preset. You need to use the `react` preset specifically to get the appropriate JSX transforms:

```
$ npm install babel-preset-react
```

and in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```